# i am trying to use subprocess module to run a terminal command which consists of an html file

Tags: linux, bash, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I am trying to build this script here which will accept a tracking number as an input, build the URL and then get the HTML response. I am trying to display this response in the terminal using the html2text program. I am trying to emulate the command "html2text filename" which is typed in the terminal into my python script, however the raw HTML file is displayed instead of the standard html2text output. where am i going wrong here ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#trial using bash calls no html2text library

import requests
import subprocess # to execute bash commands

try:
    check_for_package = subprocess.Popen(("dpkg","-s","html2text"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    output = subprocess.check_output(("grep", "Status"), stdin=check_for_package.stdout)
    check_for_package.wait()
    opstr=str(output, 'utf-8')
    print(opstr)
    if opstr == "Status: install ok installed\n" :
        print("Package installed")

except:
    print("installing html2text..............................")
    install_pkg = subprocess.check_call("sudo apt install html2text", shell=True)

r = requests.get("http://ipsweb.ptcmysore.gov.in/ipswebtracking/IPSWeb_item_events.asp?itemid=RT404715658HK&Submit=Submit")
print(r.status_code)

raw_html=r.text
#print(raw_html)
#raw_html = str(raw_html , 'utf-8')

view_html = subprocess.Popen(["html2text", raw_html])
output = view_html.communicate()
view_html.wait()
#view_html = subprocess.Popen("html2text template", shell=True)
print(output)
```

**Update:** I have got around the issue currently but storing the output of r.text in a file and then calling it with html2text

Comment: The argument to `html2text` is supposed to be a URL. If you already have the HTML, it needs to be passed as standard input to the command, not as an argument.

Comment: Why don't you just use the URL from your `requests.get()` call as the argument to `html2text`?

Answer (score 1):

The version of `html2text` you're using expects the argument to be a filename, not the HTML. To provide the HTML to it, you need to run the command with no argument, and provide the HTML on its standard input.

```
view_html = subprocess.Popen(["html2text"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
view_html.stdin.write(raw_html)
view_html.stdin.close() # Close the pipe so html2text will get EOF
output = view_html.stdout.read()
```

Comment: i did try your solution but it still says : Cannot open input file "www.google.com".
(None, None) . Any way to get around this ?

Comment: I don't see how that's related to this command. There's no mention of `www.google.com` in it.

Comment: i am using html2text that comes with ubuntu http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/html2text.1.html

Comment: just used Google as a test url ! it doesnt work with the url specified in the code either.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using [this version](https://linux.die.net/man/1/html2text)

Comment: @Barmar, that looks like the same utility, but some wording is different, the page you've linked to doesn't appear to mention a version, and the author's URL cited hasn't been valid since late 2007. And while the latest version predates that, including the current origin is probably useful: **http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/**, and if you use a tool like this that varies by distribution and OS, best to mention the version you used for your answer, as things do get customized from time to time. (How often does one get to teach grandma to suck eggs?! ;) )

Comment: version 1.3.2a doesn't seem to support url as argument ? what is my other option ?

Comment: Didn't you see the rewrite of my answer?